# Pi Nas Issue - HDD not visible in OMV

Tags: hard-drive

I recently got a brand new Model 4B (2GB), an Argon EON Pi NAS enclosure and a 4TB WD Red NAS Hard Drive.

I have connected everything up and installed OS Lite (64 bit) and Open Media Vault on the Pi. At this point, I think I should be able to attach the HDD and OMV should detect it, allowing me to format, wipe, setup the drive or whatever I want.

However, the drive is not detected by OMV and indeed when I power up the Pi, the HDD makes strange noises. It seems to me possible that I have a faulty HDD, but maybe there could be some other problem? Is there any way I can troubleshoot what is happening?

I have made a short [video](https://imgur.com/a/zD11rAG) of the Pi booting up, since this demonstrates the strange noises the drive makes - is it possible that it is not getting enough power or something?

Any assistance or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the issue might be, but I guess it could be related to storage on USB. The power shouldn't be an issue at all, as your external enclosure is powered by a 60W power supply (12Vx5A=60W).

I have a suggestion, mostly if you have money to waste. For between 100-150USD you can get an OrangePi 5 Plus, that is basically a very powerful Raspberry PI with an M.2 slot with 4 PCIe lanes, 4-32GB of RAM and GPIO pins (that even has PWM on several pins). In the M.2 slot, you can either mount an NVME drive or a 5 port SATA controller. I suppose that this will work a lot better and be much better suited for Open Media Vault.

Of course, you'll have to supply power to the drives in this setup, this can be done in several ways, the easiest is probably to add a pico power supply.